# A free group and Galois theory.

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory

Let $ F_S $ be a free group with finite generating set $ S $.

How to show that, there exists a Galois extension $ E $ of the rational numbers $ \mathbb{Q} $ such that, $ \operatorname{Gal}( E / \mathbb{Q} ) = F_S $ ?

Thank you for the help.

***Re-edit***,

Let $ F_S $ be a free profinite group which is the profinite completion of a free group with finite generating set $ S $.

How to show that, there exists a Galois extension $ E $ of the rational numbers $ \mathbb{Q} $ such that, $ \operatorname{Gal}( E / \mathbb{Q} ) = F_S $ ?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Don't Galois groups have to be more-or-less profinite?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  :-)

Comment: As paul garrett says, Galois groups must be profinite, and profinite groups are either finite or uncountable and so can't be countable. Do you mean to ask that the Galois group be the free *profinite* group on $S$?

Comment: Why are Galois groups are profinite in this case as you say both ? :-)

Comment: Yes, the Galois group is the free profinite group on $ S $.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057432/galois-group-is-a-profinite-group . Why do you believe this is true? Were you given this as an exercise?

Comment: No. 
I'm interested in Inverse Galois problem, and, i try to write, every finite group $ G $, as $ G = (S,R) = F_S / \langle \langle R \rangle \rangle = Gal ( E / \mathbb{Q} ) / \langle \langle R \rangle \rangle $.

Comment: @Qiaochu, you said that, Galois groups must be profinite, and profinite groups are either finite or uncountable and so can't be countable. Can you tell me why do you want that Galois groups must be countable ?. I don't understand this point.

Comment: @YoYo12: every free group on a finite (nonempty) set of generators is countable, so no such group is profinite.

Comment: Thank you @Qiaochu. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "free group" replaced by "free profinite group," this is either false or an open problem. If it were known to be true it would imply that every finite group $G$ occurs as the Galois group of a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and this is [not known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem).

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain to me why it imply that every finite group $ G $ occurs as the Galois group of a finite Galois extension of $ \mathbb{Q} $.

Comment: @YoYo12, if the _universal_ (=free) profinite group on any number of (topological?) generators occurs as a Galois group (of an infinite extension), then all its quotients occur. I suspect you'd benefit from some reflection on why Galois groups of _infinite_ (algebraic!) extensions are necessarily profinite, and then return to a revised version of your question.

Comment: @Paul, you say that, if the universal profinite group on any number of (topological?) generators occurs as a Galois group (of an infinite extension), then all its quotients occur. Can you explain to me why ? Thank you.  :-D

Comment: @YoYo12, well, that assertion is essentially the extended main theorem of Galois theory. The purely finite version is well known, and the profinite version is basically a definitional extension.